# how to change the text of option in select in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a page contain the select code as follows:

```
<select id="select-choice">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option> 
    <option value="1">red</option> 
    <option value="2">white</option> 
</select>
```

How can I change the text of option 1 from red to green after the page finishes loading? So far I have the following:

```
//following is the code
$('#newoutagePage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    $('#select-choice[value="1"]').text("green");
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select option instead of select box. see [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/epibab/15/edit)

[jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Selectors&redirect=no)

```
      $('#select-choice option[value="1"]').text('green');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#newoutagePage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
    $('#select-choice option[value="1"]').text("green");
}
                     ^
                     |
                 Space Here
```

The text is part of the option and not the select as a whole . You need to get the text based on  the option which is inside select..

Comment: i get the another problem i found out after change the text, it won't display right now, otherwise it will change the text after i click the select menu.

Comment: Looks like you are binding this to an event right.. So it will only change once that event is fired